# Program to instantly host a mysql database from a dump file

Tags: mysql, debugging, database, testing, dump

I'm looking for a utility program which can take a dump of a mysql database and basically host a "fake" or minimal mysql server with that data for testing another program which requires it.

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Thanks.

Comment: A fully operational mysql server is not fake - it is the mysql server itself.

Comment: What is the necessity of fake `mysql` server? What the term "fake" actually means? Why not installing mysql swever and restoring the backup?

Comment: fake, crude, etc. maybe the server does not have a full implementation of mysql's language? who knows.. I am asking if anybody knows of such a tool

Comment: <humor>MariaDB</humor>. (Actually not accurate anyway, since it has *more* features than MySQL, not less.)  Seriously, no, you'll not find such a tool.  It would be ridiculously complicated to emulate a working database from a dump file, and for every feature not provided, it would be that much less useful.  If you want to test against MySQL, test against MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the dump as proper inserts, and it doesn't use any mysql specific features, you can try to load it in [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org) database. That's about as minimalistic as it goes. Note, however, that you won't be able to test it with the same code as used for mysql, since sqlite does not have a server. Your code will have to open the sqlite db file instead and do the statements on it. Most programming languages have sqlite support.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is provided by MySQL itself.

Install the MySQL server, start it, then load the dump with

```
mysql -uroot -p < mydump.sql
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it looks like the tool does not exist. I was thinking of something more like a wrapper around mysql-sandbox.